# CoffeeScript -> Javascript, ??? -> Erlang

Tags: erlang

Is there any language that compiles in Erlang, like CoffeeScript for javsacript?

Comment: not true. Erlang ain't ugly to me

Comment: @MuzaayaJoshua, semicolons and dots at the end of line looks wrong for me. Also if there were such coffescript for erlang, it could introduce something like prettier hashes, or module names based on filename, or function call without brackets. I am not sure what else I would like to see, but I feel like erlang's syntax could be improved.

Comment: @welldan97 erlang is not like your usual scripting language. get a grasp of it and you will love the simplicity of it's syntax(yes, really, the simplicity).

Comment: http://elixir-lang.org/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are languages that compile to Erlang (or Erlang byte-code). The ones I know of are:

- [Efene](http://www.marianoguerra.com.ar/efene/), which sounds like what you want.
- [Mercury](http://www.mercury.csse.unimelb.edu.au/), which can compile to Erlang but is almost certainly not what you want.

Comment: and elixir: https://github.com/josevalim/elixir

Comment: Elixir looks like what I searched for. Thanks, I'm going to look closer to it.

Comment: Meanwhile, Elixir moved to http://elixir-lang.org/

Answer (score 6):

If you like lisp there is: https://github.com/rvirding/lfe